# Restarting NHibernate Session after an database exception, without CurrentContext

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, nhibernate

According to http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#manipulatingdata-exceptions, after a database exception the Session should be discarded.

Now, in our web app, in some cases, it's normal to throw and catch ADOExceptions. For instance for constraint violations.

According to the document linked to we should then abandon the session. However, we still want to do some work with the database if we get a constraint violation so I need a new session.

In our tests we do this by calling

```
CurrentSessionContext.Unbind(SessionFactory).Close();
CurrentSessionContext.Bind(SessionFactory.OpenSession());
```

but in the web app we don't use CurrentSessionContext, we use [LazySessionContext](http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2011/03/03/effective-nhibernate-session-management-for-web-apps.aspx). So we can't directly reference the CurrentSessionContext in our business classes since it isn't used from the web and we can't reference the LazySessionContext since the HttpContext is not available during integration testing.

Is there a way to dispose and recreate a session and connect it to the current context, **without** directly referencing the context class? I have the SessionFactory object and the Session object.

Comment: Updated link for NHibernate reference: http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#manipulatingdata-exceptions

Answer (score 0):

Without wanting to sound critical I would suggest that you need to rethink the design of your application. You should implement an interface either through the use of combo boxes for instance or validation that would prevent users entering data that would cause ADOExceptions such as constraint violations. If these do then occur they are then exceptional circumstances that you can report to your users as an internal error and maybe log that error through a separate mechanism such as through the health monitoring built into ASP.NET.

I would also add that your entities may need another look as constraint violations are not something you normally need to worry about when you are using NHibernate.

Comment: It's not that easy in multi user applications. What if user A tries to save a new EntityA with a reference to an EntityB just a second after a user B deleted EntityB?

Comment: @cremor Implement locking optimisitic or pessimistic depending on your use case.

Comment: Optimistic locking failures are Exceptions too. And locking all tables which can be referenced from EntityA as long as any user has an editing or creation UI for EntityA open isn't practical.

Comment: @cremor Locking entity A may well be practical in some circumstances. But I take your point about optimistic locking.

Comment: You should prevent the save at the UI, the chances of User A doing what User B is doing at the same time is pretty slim. Prevent it at the UI, failsafe it with the DB constraint. Then handle the exception appropriately. In this case your save failed, thats your UoW, doing other things with in that UoW shouldn't be part of the same session.

Comment: I see your point, but it's not practical in this case to change the design. There's several reasons to this: multi-user as mentioned, the existing database design and a legacy application that we're replacing but for now we're sharing the database. So for the moment, we're stuck with handling some Oracle exceptions.